# Creating multiple plots from a list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a Python list that looks something like this using matplotlib:

```
[['125Hz', 0, 55.9], 
['125Hz', 30, 54.9], 
['125Hz', 60, 52.2], 
['125Hz', 90, 51.5], 
['125Hz', 120, 51.1], 
['125Hz', 150, 49.6], 
['125Hz', 180, 50.4], 
['250Hz', 0, 57.0], 
['250Hz', 30, 56.1], 
['250Hz', 60, 53.8], 
['250Hz', 90, 52.2], 
['250Hz', 120, 50.7], 
['250Hz', 150, 48.2], 
['250Hz', 180, 48.1], 
['500Hz', 0, 58.0],
....
]
```

I need separate curves for each appearing frequency (eg.`125Hz, 250Hz...`). I haven't found a solution so far. I would also like to use the frequency string as my label in my plot.

What is the best practice to perform such an operation?

Edit: It has to be a dynamic method, as I dont know beforehand how many frequencys/graphs I'll get. The items per frequency could also vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with this sort of tabular data is `pandas`, which has lots of functionality built-in to it for grouping data. In your case, this could look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.array([['125Hz', 0, 55.9], 
['125Hz', 30, 54.9], 
['125Hz', 60, 52.2], 
['125Hz', 90, 51.5], 
['125Hz', 120, 51.1], 
['125Hz', 150, 49.6], 
['125Hz', 180, 50.4], 
['250Hz', 0, 57.0], 
['250Hz', 30, 56.1], 
['250Hz', 60, 53.8], 
['250Hz', 90, 52.2], 
['250Hz', 120, 50.7], 
['250Hz', 150, 48.2], 
['250Hz', 180, 48.1], 
['500Hz', 0, 58.0]])

# Create a pandas dataframe from your numpy array:
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['freq','x','y'])

# cast x and y to numeric types:
df[['x','y']] = df[['x','y']].astype(float)

# Group by frequency, and plot your variables
for freq, data in df.groupby('freq'):
    plt.plot(data.x, data.y, label=freq)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

With your data, you get something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats exactly what I was looking for!